# How to center the dot inside a radio input type

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

Having a reusable Radio group component, I'm using styled components for the styling of it.

The dot should be placed right in the center of the circle which is (kind of) working in the next screenshot:

[image]

However it feels to be a little bit too low and too right.

Also, the styling that I'm using can be made better for sure:

```
import { StyledRadioButton, Radio, Wrapper } from './radio-button.styles';

...

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Radio type="radio" id={id} disabled={disabled} {...rest} />
      <StyledRadioButton htmlFor={id}>{label}</StyledRadioButton>
    </Wrapper>
  );
```

**Styled:**

```
export const Wrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  align-items: center;
`;

export const Radio = styled.input`
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: normal;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  ::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 0.75em;
    height: 0.75em;
    margin: 4.26px; // this is the tweak to position it into the center
  }
  :checked {
    ::after {
      background-color: green;
    }
    border: 1px solid green;
  }
  border: 1px solid grey;
`;


export const StyledRadioButton = styled.label<{ disabled?: boolean }>`
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16pc;
  color: black;
`;
```

Answer (score 1):

Today, you can use CSS (inline-)grid for easy centering of content. No need to make the `radio::after` a `block` and use `margin` to reposition the 'dot'.

I converted your code to a runnable snippet and:

- added `display: inline-grid; place-items: center;` to `.radio`
- disabled `display` and `margin` in `.radio::after`
- created a responsive demo to toy with
- made the `radio` size and border dependend on parent font-size.

```css
.wrapper {
    font-size: var(--defaults-radio);
}

.radio {
    /* Disable defaults */
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    margin: 0;

    width    : 1.5em;
    height   : 1.5em;
    font-size: var(--defaults-radio, 1em); /* from 16px, with fallback */
    font-style: normal;

    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 0.0625em solid grey; /* 0.0625em = 1px */

    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;

    display: inline-grid; place-items: center;
}
.radio::after {
    content: "";
/*    display: block; /**/
    border-radius: 50%;
    width : 0.75em;
    height: 0.75em;
/*    margin: 4.26px;/**/
}
.radio:checked {
    border-color: green;
}
.radio:checked::after {
    background-color: green;
}

/* This and thats for the demo */
input[type="range"] { width: 100% }
label>input         { display: block; font-size: 1em }
label               { margin-bottom: 0.5rem }
```

```html
<label><b>radio size</b>&nbsp;-&nbsp;[0.5 - 5em] <span id="info-radio"></span>
    <input type="range" min="0.5" max="5" step="0.5" value="1"
           oninput="document.body.style.setProperty('--defaults-radio', this.value + 'em');
                    document.getElementById('info-radio').innerHTML = ' > ' + this.value + 'em';">
</label>
<br>
<div class="wrapper">
    <input class="radio" type="radio" name="group">&nbsp;<input class="radio" type="radio" name="group" checked>
</div>
```